# How to apply baseline on a specific component in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, clearcase, jenkins-plugins, clearcase-ucm

Is there a plugin in Jenkins that enables to define a specific component on which I want to apply baseline (fully) - Except using cleartool mkbl command ?

Answer (score 1):

If the [Jenkins UCM plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+UCM+Plugin) doesn't work for you, the easiest way would be to define a custom job, or a post build step, with a command like [`cleartool mkbl`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkbl.htm):

```
cleartool mkbl -full -component component:myComponent@\MyPVob -view <view_tag>
```

Now the easiest way is to have a dedicated stream ready, with that component only, for which you can define a Jenkins UCM job for it to put a baseline (or for you to define a post-build step, with the `mkbl command`)

In both cases, that involve an UCM view, with that component added as a writable component.

Comment: Hi Von,
I meant except this command I'm already familiar with..
But I understand there is no way to do it without a dedicated stream, Thanks anyway :-)

Comment: @Sigalit yes, a dedicated stream is best to manage that kind of label production.